# Class stored properties not supported in classes; did you mean 'static'?

Tags: swift, protocols

**This works fine**

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    static func someMethod()
}

class SomeType: SomeProtocol {
    class func someMethod() {
        print("someMethod called")
    }
}

SomeType.someMethod() // prints someMethod called
```

Question1:
`Static` function defines in `SomeProtocol` confirmed by `SomeType`, Here we can substitute `Static` function with `class` function. And its works fine. Why?

**This gives compile time error:** *Class stored properties not supported in classes; did you mean 'static'?*

```
protocol SomeAnotherProtocol {
    static var someProperty: Int { get set }
}

class SomeAnotherType: SomeAnotherProtocol {
    class var someProperty: Int = 10 // Error:  Class stored properties not supported in classes; did you mean 'static'?
}

SomeAnotherType.someProperty
```

Question2:
`Static` attribute defines in `SomeAnotherProtocol` confirmed by `SomeAnotherType`, Here we can substitute `Static` attribute with `class` attribute. And it does not works fine and giving compile time error. Why?

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These are just language rules.

[Type Methods:](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/methods/#Type-Methods)

> You can also define methods that are called on the type itself. These kinds of methods are called *type methods*. You indicate type methods by writing the `static` keyword before the method’s `func` keyword. Classes can use the `class` keyword instead, to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation of that method.

[Type Property Syntax:](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties#Type-Property-Syntax)

> You define type properties with the `static` keyword. For computed type properties for class types, you can use the `class` keyword instead to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation.

[Method Requirements of Protocols:](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/protocols#Method-Requirements)

> As with type property requirements, you always prefix type method requirements with the `static` keyword when they’re defined in a protocol. This is true even though type method requirements are prefixed with the `class` or `static` keyword when implemented by a class.